# Access a flask template dictionary variable

Tags: python, flask

I have a `flask` variable `{{blogposts}}` that outputs:

```
[{u'MONTH': 12, u'YEAR': 2016, u'post_name': u'data here', u'post_title': u'data here'}, 
{u'MONTH': 12, u'YEAR': 2016, u'post_name': u'data here', u'post_title': u"data here"}, 
{u'MONTH': 12, u'YEAR': 2016, u'post_name': u'data here', u'post_title': u'data here'}]
```

i have a flask template that outputs this like:

```
<ul>
    {% for blogpost in blogposts %}
        <li>
            <a href="http://blog.site.com/wordpress/{{blogpost.MONTH}}/{{blogpost.YEAR}}/{{blogpost.post_name}}">
                {{blogpost.post_title}}
            </a>
        </li>
    {% else %}
        <li>no blog posts right now...</li>
    {% endfor %}
        <div class="clearL"> </div>
    </ul>
```

**RENDERED HTML**

```
<li>
                    <a href="http://blog.site.com/wordpress///">

                    </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="http://blog.site.com/wordpress///">

                    </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="http://blog.site.com/wordpress///">

                    </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="http://blog.site.com/wordpress///">

                    </a>
                </li>
```

**I want to access the `value` for the** `month`, `year`, post_name' and `post_title` (in this order), instead its outputting:

```
 MONTH YEAR post_name post_title MONTH YEAR post_name post_title MONTH YEAR post_name post_title
```

How can I accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: Er, in exactly the same way as you would anywhere else. In any case, you clearly have three of each of those values; which do you want to access?

Comment: Daniel please see above. I want to access `month`, `year`, `post_name`, `post_title`

Comment: See what above? You still have three of each of these values.

Comment: The values i'd like to access. Can you please help

Comment: Question is clear enough, just try the answer I wrote and see if it helps

Comment: @lapinkoira - this doesnt work. The script fails, are you sure your syntax is right?

Comment: mmm there was a } missing, try again, which was the error anyway?

Comment: See updated with template - still isnt working - am i missing something?>

Comment: print {{blogposts}} and {{blogpost}}

Comment: @lapinkoira - see my updated post and what i want. im getting something, but not what i want. thx

Comment: I see, I updated my answer, could you try it?

Comment: im getting no data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
{% for blogpost in blogposts %}
    <p> Month: {{ blogpost.MONTH }} </p> 
    <p> Year: {{ blogpost.YEAR }} </p> 
    <p> Name: {{ blogpost.post_name }}</p> 
    <p> Title: {{ blogpost.post_title }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: No, blogposts is a list of dicts.

Comment: Um you rock, i think im rusty on dictionaries and lists overall. I'll read up on some things ... thanks sooooooooooooo much!

Comment: np, glad I helped!

Comment: So, i thought this worked, but now im getting nothing after a refresh

Comment: Can you post the source code it renders? What's inside the <a>? empty values?

Comment: see above please.

Comment: I think the code is right but the dictionary is empty, can you print <p>{{blogpost}}</p> before the <a> link?

Comment: That means it's empty, check your flask server app.py code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132123/discussion-between-lapinkoira-and-jshee).

Comment: The issue is in the `template` you must put a space in between echoed values this is `WRONG {{value}}` this is RIGHT: `{{ value }}` (see the spaces)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Can try this !! 
    {% for row_index in blogposts %}
     {% for key,value in row_index.iteritems() %}
              {{key|safe}}
          {{ value|safe }}
      <br><br>
    {% endfor %}
     {% endfor %}

Even this can work 
    {% for row_index in blogposts %}
     {% for key in row_index.iteritems() %}
              {{key|safe}}
          {{ row_index[key]|safe }}
      <br><br>
    {% endfor %}
     {% endfor %}
```